# Wordpress Gravity Form Strange error in Multi Page Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity

I went into a strange problem with a Multi Page Gravity form on my wordpress site, this is the link to the form:
http://cc.marknetdev.com/small-business/apply-for-a-loan/apply-now/

The form neither show validation error nor jump to next step once I press submit/next.

I investigated this problem and found that this problem is only occuring on this server, I tried the same installation on a different domain and hosting and it is working there:
http://comcap.taqih.com/small-business/apply-for-a-loan/apply-now/

I tried updating htaccess file, deactivating all the plugins, trying the same thing on new wordpress installation but the problem is occuring again and again on this page:
http://cc.marknetdev.com/small-business/apply-for-a-loan/apply-now/

Can you help me, what is wrong? Is it related to server?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked PHP, plugin and Wp versions? Maybe they are different.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, both the versions are same:

Comment: Just php version is different:
PHP: 5.3.18[cc.marknetdev.com(the site which has problem)] & 5.2.17[comcap.taqih.com (the site on which there is no problem)]

However wordpress and Gravity form versions are up to date i.e.
Wordpress: 3.4.2
Gravity Forms: 1.6.9 [latest]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem:

"Mod Security on my server was blocking the form submission, since form has lots of input, it was considering it as a spam attack, and was blocking that form submission"

I hope this will be helpful for someone in future.